# Convert Kinect Beta to version 1.8

Tags: c#, kinect

So I have convert the "KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData" from the beta version of the Kinect SDK to the version 1.8. Here's what I have right now

**The Original**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.Research.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui;
using Coding4Fun.Kinect.WinForm;

namespace KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Runtime nui;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nui = new Runtime();
        nui.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking | RuntimeOptions.UseColor);
        nui.VideoStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Video, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, ImageType.Color);

        nui.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(nui_SkeletonFrameReady);
        nui.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nui_VideoFrameReady);
    }

    void nui_VideoFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        picColorVideo.Image = e.ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
    }

    void nui_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        // 迴圈有可能跑多次 (多個玩家被追蹤)
        foreach(SkeletonData data in e.SkeletonFrame.Skeletons)
        {
            // 只要處理正在被追蹤的玩家
            if (data.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                JointsCollection jc = data.Joints;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (JointID jid in Enum.GetValues(typeof(JointID)))
                {
                    if (jid != JointID.Count)
                    {
                        //Vector v = jc[jid].Position;
                        //sb.Append(string.Format("{0} = {1}, {2}, {3}\n", jid, v.X, v.Y, v.Z));

                        Point p = GetDisplayPosition(jc[jid]);
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0} = {1}, {2}\n", jid, p.X, p.Y));
                    }
                }

                lblJoins.Text = sb.ToString(); 
            }
        }
    }

    // 轉換關節座標到螢幕座標
    private Point GetDisplayPosition(Joint joint)
    {
        float depthX, depthY;
        nui.SkeletonEngine.SkeletonToDepthImage(joint.Position, out depthX, out depthY);
        depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));  // 轉換到 320 x 240 空間系統
        depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));
        int colorX, colorY;
        nui.NuiCamera.GetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixel(ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, new ImageViewArea(), (int)depthX, (int)depthY, (short)0, out colorX, out colorY);
        return new Point(colorX * picColorVideo.Width / 640, colorY * picColorVideo.Height / 480);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        nui.Uninitialize();
    }

    }
}
```

**My Version**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Coding4Fun.Kinect.WinForm;

namespace KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    KinectSensor sensor;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
        sensor.Start();
        sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

        sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(nui_SkeletonFrameReady);

        sensor.ColorFrameReady += new EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(ColorImageReady);


        //sensor.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nui_VideoFrameReady);
    }

    byte[] pixelData;
    void ColorImageReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        bool receivedData = false;
        using (ColorImageFrame colorImageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorImageFrame != null)
            {
                if (pixelData == null)
                //allocate the first time
                {
                    pixelData = new byte[colorImageFrame.PixelDataLength];
                }
                colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
                receivedData = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // apps processing of image data is taking too long, it got more than 2 frames behind.
                // the data is no longer avabilable.
            }
            if (receivedData)
            {
                // DISPLAY OR PROCESS IMAGE DATA IN pixelData HERE
            }
        }
    }
    //void nui_VideoFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    picColorVideo.Image = e.ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
    //}

    void nui_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        // 迴圈有可能跑多次 (多個玩家被追蹤)
        foreach(Skeleton data in e.SkeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo)
        {
            // 只要處理正在被追蹤的玩家
            if (data.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                JointCollection jc = data.Joints;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (JointID jid in Enum.GetValues(typeof(JointID)))
                {
                    if (jid != JointID.Count)
                    {
                        //Vector v = jc[jid].Position;
                        //sb.Append(string.Format("{0} = {1}, {2}, {3}\n", jid, v.X, v.Y, v.Z));

                        Point p = GetDisplayPosition(jc[jid]);
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0} = {1}, {2}\n", jid, p.X, p.Y));
                    }
                }

                lblJoins.Text = sb.ToString(); 
            }
        }
    }

    // 轉換關節座標到螢幕座標
    //private Point GetDisplayPosition(Joint joint)
    //{
    //    float depthX, depthY;
    //    sensor.SkeletonStream.SkeletonToDepthImage(joint.Position, out depthX, out depthY);
    //    depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));  // 轉換到 320 x 240 空間系統
    //    depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));
    //    int colorX, colorY;
    //    sensor.NuiCamera.GetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixel(ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, new ImageViewArea(), (int)depthX, (int)depthY, (short)0, out colorX, out colorY);
    //    return new Point(colorX * picColorVideo.Width / 640, colorY * picColorVideo.Height / 480);
    //}
    private Point getDisplayPosition(DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Joint joint)
    {
        float depthX, depthY;
        DepthImagePoint depthPoint = sensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(joint.Position, depthImageFormat);

        depthX = depthPoint.X;
        depthY = depthPoint.Y;

        depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
        depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));

        int colorX, colorY;
        ColorImagePoint colorPoint = depthFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y, sensor.ColorStream.Format);
        colorX = colorPoint.X;
        colorY = colorPoint.Y;

        return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        sensor.Stop();
    }

    }
}
```

it still have some problems,how to fix it

---

the screen capture bellow are the problems
[P1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHA4P.png)
[P2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylPK6.png)

**Errors**:

1.
'Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'SkeletonFrame' and no extension method 'SkeletonFrame' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\06. 骨架追蹤與螢幕座標轉換\KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData\Form1.cs    73

2.
'Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonStream' does not contain a definition for 'SkeletonToDepthImage' and no extension method 'SkeletonToDepthImage' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\06. 骨架追蹤與螢幕座標轉換\KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData\Form1.cs  102

3.
'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor' does not contain a definition for 'NuiCamera' and no extension method 'NuiCamera' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\06. 骨架追蹤與螢幕座標轉換\KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData\Form1.cs  106

4.
The name 'ImageResolution' does not exist in the current context    D:\06. 骨架追蹤與螢幕座標轉換\KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData\Form1.cs  106

5.
The type or namespace name 'ImageViewArea' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
D:\06. 骨架追蹤與螢幕座標轉換\KinectSkeletalTrackingGetJointData\Form1.cs  106

----------------------------------------------------------------------------2014/5/13

Comment: What problems are there?

Comment: the link bellow are the problems
[link](http://i.imgur.com/xmbFNhw.png)

Comment: did you fix your problem? I am also having the same issues.